# Code igniter - 404 not found, routes issue, ssh server

Tags: codeigniter, url, ssh, routes

So first off, I am pretty familiar with codeigniter I've used it for multiple occasions. Right now I have a project too do for school and I installed codeigniter on the server but I am getting routing issues I believe.

So additional info about the server which is different from the normal environment I work with, the server uses SSH and it is very weirdly protected in my opinion. You also need a username and password to view the URL in the first place. (I think it's weird)

If this helps the url is:
https://clipper.encs.concordia.ca/~pyc353_2/
and credentials are (username: pyc353_2, password: FMaqRb)

Now I am able to see any page that I set as my 'default_controller' in the routes, but the problem is trying to go to any other page. Right now I'm trying to access the register controller and I just get 404'd (while it works if I set it as default)

I will link all the code I think may be relevant to the error, hopefully it's not server settings since I have no control over any change.

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://clipper.encs.concordia.ca/~pyc353_2/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "test";
```

.htaccess (there may be better code for doing this but I used it in the past no problem and the route doesn't work even if I remove htaccess and add back index.php to 'index_page')

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 
</IfModule>
```

So I tried accessing my pagedifferent variations in the url such as: (stackoverflow won't let me post more than 2 physical links)

clipper.encs.concordia.ca/~pyc353_2/register

clipper.encs.concordia.ca/~pyc353_2/index.php/register

neither work although with /index.php/ the error message is: "No input file specified."

So I hope my explanations are clear enough, it's hard to explain something I don't understand the source problem. If you need any additional info feel free to ask. I really need to solve this to proceed at all for my project.

**EDIT**

I don't know if this is relevant but the 404 message is not even in the codeigniter style it just looks like a plain web 404

Also I am looking at the path on the server and this is the hierarchy: /www/groups/p/py_comp353_2 I don't know if that could affect anything also?

**NEWER EDIT**

Following what I found here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/troubleshooting.html

Changing index.php to index.php? (and removing htaccess) actually did make the routing work. Now I am happy enough with this and I can continue working, but being that it's an ugly solve would anyone know how to keep the routing working AND remove the index.php? from my URI?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your htaccess is not working.

To confirm, create a new PHP file and write this line:

```
echo phpinfo();
```

On that page try to search for "mod_rewrite", if it is enabled, you will see it under "Loaded Modules"

It is probable, it is not enabled.

Try this on your server:

```
a2enmod enable
```

Then restart the apache server.

For restarting on debian, this should work:

```
service apache2 restart
```

For CentOS, this should work:

```
apachectl restart
```

That always does not solve the problem.

Even then, try your CI installation in the normal mode after that. (With everything in normal mode: htaccess as before, and no index.php in the URL)

If it does not work, you may need to alter the apache config file httpd.conf

Try to search for this line:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Uncomment it by removing the # sign

Restart Apache Server.

Test it now, again.

There could still be other things that you could do to enable mod_rewrite.